# How to trigger keyup function after certain number of strokes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-forms

I have made a simple form where I should enter a phone number split into three section first input takes 3, second input takes 3 and last should take 4. I have set `maxlength` for the input elements, I'm calling the `keyup` to focus on to the next element. But instead of 3 strokes it jumps to the next input after I enter a single number.

Here's my [codesandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-v5txuw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for you to play around

Here's my HTML

```html
<div class="form-group" style="height:70px;">
  <label class="reg_txt">Phone Number  <span>*</span></label>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="wsite-form">
    <input type="text" class="text input-name1" formControlName="phone1" maxlength="3" (keyup)="nextStep($event,1)" (focus)="focused(1)" id="code1">
  </div>
  <div class="line">-</div>
  <div class="wsite-form">
    <input type="text" class="text input-name1" formControlName="phone2" maxlength="3" (keyup)="nextStep($event,2)" (focus)="focused(2)" id="code2">
  </div>
  <div class="line">-</div>
  <div class="wsite-form">
    <input type="text" class="text input-name1" formControlName="phone3" maxlength="4" (keyup)="nextStep($event,3)" (focus)="focused(3)" id="code3">
  </div>

</div>
```

Here's my component method

```
nextStep(event, step: number): void {
  const prevElement = document.getElementById('code' + (step - 1));
  const nextElement = document.getElementById('code' + (step + 1));
  console.log(event)
  if (event.code == 'Backspace' && event.target.value === '') {
    event.target.parentElement.parentElement.children[step - 2 > 0 ? step - 2 : 0].children[0].value = ''
    if (prevElement) {
      prevElement.focus()
      return
    }
  } else {
    if (nextElement) {
      nextElement.focus()
      return
    } else {

    }
  }
}
```

and also If I hit backspace it should jump to previous element it works for the second input box and it throws error for the last element. I know I made a silly mistake, could anybody point me in the right direction. I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: on every keyup event you can check length of input, and if its above max length then you can go for selecting next input and same for previous input selectiont too!!

Comment: I'll try that and get back to you

Comment: @GaurangDhorda that doesn't work sadly\

Comment: How does @GaurangDhorda 's proposed solution "not work" for you?  Surely verifying that the input is completely and correctly filled out is a more robust approach than counting arbitrary keystrokes, which could be arrow or delete keystrokes...

Comment: @AlexanderNied I tried to convert the target value to string logged it in the console. It consoled 3.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda it works man, I tried convert to string which is wrong idea.

Comment: FWIW, if this is code that others will be working with you may want to add linting to your project-- at a glance I see missing semicolons, weak equality checking and superfluous logic nesting ...

Comment: @AlexanderNied noted man, thanks for pointing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this `if (nextElement && event.target.value.length === 3)` to your else statement at the bottom of `nextStep()` works instead of just `if (nextElement)`.

If there is a next element to go to *and* the current length of the input is 3, focus on the next element.

Comment: I tried converting the target value to string and compared the length, I should've try this. This works, thanks. But one more question if you hit backspace on the third it throws error do you know why. But it works for second box

Comment: It's trying to get the value of an undefined element. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve with this line `event.target.parentElement.parentElement.children[step - 2 > 0 ? step - 2 : 0].children[0].value = ''`

Comment: I'm passing step from the view and checking the value of sibling element

Comment: Removing that line works for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also create a directive (*) like

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'input[maxlength]',
  exportAs: 'child'
})
export class MaxLengthDirective {
  @Input()prev:HTMLElement;
  @Input()next:HTMLElement;

  @HostListener('keyup',['$event']) _(event:any){
     if (!event.target.value && this.prev && event.key=='Backspace')
       this.prev.focus()
     if (event.target.value.length==this.maxLength && this.next)
      this.next.focus()
  }
  constructor(@Attribute('maxlength') private maxLength:number){}
}
```

You can use like

```
<input #one maxlength="3" [next]="two">
<input #two [prev]="one" [next]="three" maxlength="4">
<input #three [prev]="two" maxlength="5">
```

See the [stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bebmnx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

(*)Don't forget include in declarations of your module

**Update** Yes, I think also that is a bit complex use the template reference variables and `[prev]` and `[next]` so, Why not improve?

For this we use two directives

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'input[maxlength]',
  exportAs: 'child'
})
export class MaxLengthDirective {

  @HostListener('keyup',['$event']) _(event:any){
     if (!event.target.value && event.key=='Backspace')
       this.parent.prev(this)
     if (event.target.value.length==this.maxLength)
      this.parent.next(this)
  }
  constructor(@Attribute('maxlength') private maxLength:number,@Optional() @Host() private parent:MaxLengthGroupDirective,public elementRef:ElementRef){
  }
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[maxLengthGroup]',
  exportAs: 'maxLengthGroup'
})
export class MaxLengthGroupDirective {
  @ContentChildren(MaxLengthDirective) items:QueryList<MaxLengthDirective>
  next(item:MaxLengthDirective)
  {

     const index=this.items.toArray().findIndex(x=>x==item);
     if (index<this.items.length-1)
     {
       const nextItem=this.items.find((_,i)=>i>index)
       nextItem.elementRef.nativeElement.focus()
     }
  }
  prev(item:MaxLengthDirective)
  {
    const index=this.items.toArray().findIndex(x=>x==item);
    if (index>0)
    {
      const prevItem=this.items.find((_,i)=>i==index-1)
      prevItem.elementRef.nativeElement.focus()
    }
  }
}
```

The max-length-group get the max-length using ContentChildren. So we has in a QueryList all the inputs that has matlength. Two functions inside "next" and "prev" are who focus in the prev or in the next element. For this, we need inject in the mat-length the max-length-group using `@Host` that indicate to Angular to search this directive. The use is like

```
<div max-length-group>
  <input maxlength="3" placeholder="max 3" />
  <input placeholder="max 4" maxlength="4" />
  <input placeholder="max 5" maxlength="5" />
</div>
```

The [new stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-siwjff?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmax-length-group.directive.ts)

Comment: Wow, this looks neat. I'll try this